# Region of significance analysis with a compound poisson linear model?

Tags: r, regression, distributions, interaction, compound-distributions

I conducted a hierarchical analysis with a compound Poisson linear model (cplm) in R, using the cplm package, and found a significant interaction effect. I want to perform a region-of-significance analysis to understand where, across the continuous independent variable, the effect of the binary independent variable is significant.

If it was a regular hlm analysis (e.g., using lme4) I would use the Johnson-Neuman approach (and johnson_neyman() function).

Does anyone know how can I perform a similar region-of-significance analysis when conducting a compound Poisson linear model?